# Error adding elements to an Immutable List

Tags: java, guava

The following code snippet does not compile (gives an error reporting incompatible types) :

```
private static List<IGrupoSituacoesPermitidas> grupoSituacoesPermitidas = ImmutableList.of(new GrupoSituacoesPermitidasDI());
```

But if I add more elements to the list like in the code below

```
private static List<IGrupoSituacoesPermitidas> grupoSituacoesPermitidas = ImmutableList.of(new GrupoSituacoesPermitidasDI(), new GrupoSituacoesPermitidasDV());
```

it compiles without problems.

Can anyone tell me why this happens and how to get around this without casting ?

Comment: Please show the *exact* error message - as well as showing all the different types involved and how they're related. Ideally, give us an example which uses the standard Java types so it's easier for us to reproduce.

Answer (score 6):

When you pass a single argument - `new GrupoSituacoesPermitidasDI()`, the type parameter `E` of the generic method is inferred as `GrupoSituacoesPermitidasDI`, and thus it will return a `List<GrupoSituacoesPermitidasDI>`, which is not a subtype of `List<IGrupoSituacoesPermitidas>`, and hence the compiler error.

Now, if you look at the signature of the overloaded method, it takes 2 arguments of type `E`. So, your arguments should be of same type. If it isn't, compiler infers the type as common super type of the argument you passed.

So, since you pass 2 difference arguments which are not same, the type parameter is inferred as the common super type of those types, which I guess is `IGrupoSituacoesPermitidas`, and hence the list return is `List<IGrupoSituacoesPermitidas>`, and that is fine.

Here's a simple example, which reproduces that problem:

```
class Vehicle { }
class Car extends Vehicle { }
class Bike extends Vehicle { }


public static <T> List<T> of(T obj) {
    List<T> list = new ArrayList<T>();
    list.add(obj);
    return list;
}

public static <T> List<T> of(T obj1, T obj2) {
    List<T> list = new ArrayList<T>();
    list.add(obj1);
    list.add(obj2);
    return list;
}

public static void main(String... args) {
    List<Vehicle> vehicles = of(new Car());       // Doesn't work
    List<Vehicle> vehicles1 = of(new Vehicle());  // Works
    List<Vehicle> vehicles2 = of(new Car(), new Bike());
}
```

That is how type inference works. If the two types are not same, then the common super type is inferred. Also, from the comments from @Marko, if suppose your classes also implemented `Serializable`, then the type parameter would have been inferred as:

```
Vehicle & Serializable
```

And then again, that will fail, as `List<Vehicle>` is not super type of `List<T2>` where `T2` has above two bounds.

You can solve such problems by giving explicit type argument:

```
private static List<IGrupoSituacoesPermitidas> grupoSituacoesPermitidas = 
   ImmutableList.<IGrupoSituacoesPermitidas>of(new GrupoSituacoesPermitidasDI());
```

Comment: We also know from this that those classes are not `Serializable` or `Cloneable` :)

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Yes. That is also inferred

Comment: My point: if  the classes did implement `Serializable`, the code would once again break. Type inference in Java is a drag.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Yeah, actually I meant to say, that is inferred from the fact that the code compiles :)

Answer (score -1):

Immutable means that once the object has been instantiated it can not be modified.  Your second code snippet is adding an extra item to the list during construction which is legal.

You may want to take a look at the tutorial for [Immutable Objects](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/immutable.html).

Comment: You've missed the boat with this answer... OP is not trying to add anything to the lists after construction.

Comment: You are right, I didn't read the problem carefully enough.  I assume the first snippet can be fixed by casting the single argument to IGrupoSituacoesPermitidas, but it doesn't seem like that should be necessary.

Comment: Yes, it's the ugly side of Java's type inference. It's an example of an *upcast* which actually makes sense.